# how to read netcdf4 data if I only have netcdf3 tool?

Tags: python, r, netcdf, python-xarray

- 1. My school cluster admin said: if we load netcdf4 module, then we cannot load netcdf3 module. So he refused to update netcdf4
- 2. I have a `.nc` file, which is a netcdf4 file, I think and I need to load it in R.
- 3. In R on our cluster, only `RNetCDF` package is installed. And it cannot read the above .nc file. The `ncdf4` package is not there. (I try to install it, it says it requires netcdf library of version 4. And of course I do not have `sudo`)
- 4. In python, (I don't know why) I can load `netcdf4` file. I don't know if I can use this to (save it in netcdf 3 format?) help me load that data in R.

So, how should I do?

- The admin don't want to switch to netcdf4 module, and so it seems I(or he) cannot install `ncdf4` package in R.
- Some of the `nc` data are directly downloaded from some website, and some of the `nc` files are from the output of the `xarray` package in python (and the netcdf output of xarray is in version 4).

Comment: hdf5 can read netCDF4 ...

Comment: Thanks @DavidLeBauer ! This helps. I googled this post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-hdf-files-in-r-example-pathfinder-sst-data/ , which uses the rhdf5 package in R to read nc4 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With xarray you can control the version of files saved by specifying `format='NETCDF3_CLASSIC'` when calling `to_netcdf`. So a simple solution might be to use xarray, e.g.,

```
ds = xarray.open_dataset(path)
ds.to_netcdf(dest, format='NETCDF3_CLASSIC')
```

Comment: Well, I got an error message: RuntimeError: NetCDF: One or more variable sizes violate format constraints. So, maybe it is because the dataset is too large(5.2G)?

Comment: Indeed, netCDF3 is a very old (32 bit) file format -- it doesn't support variable sizes larger than 4GB under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks! This helps, because even though I could load this data with the above `rhdf5` package, the time (date) is missing, and only shows "0,1,2,3,4,5 ...", which shows some error like "using 64 bit without losing information"...